# RESTful Spring with jQuery or Freemarker - is it still RESTful?

Tags: jquery, spring, rest, freemarker

I am now trying to setup my first RESTful project using Spring Framework. I have heard that I can handle my view for many different ways, in example using JSP's, Freemarker, Velocity - and in Spring Controllers then I would return ModelAndObject. But another way is to add @RequestBody to a controller and return pure objects as JSON(prefered by me) or XML.

Now I am trying to setup RESTful-backend with Spring and handle it with separated HTML5+jQuery project. Its for now difficult for me a little bit and I wonder about start using Freemarker/JSPs.

But I am afraid that it wont be RESTful then. I would return view, not just pure Objects and my question is: Is it still RESTful practice?

Second, a bit smaller question is: What are differences between using template languages like Freemarker/Velocity and using HTML5 + jQuery? Now, as an amateur-programmer I think that using HTML5+jQuery approach takes much more time than using eg. Freemarker. 
I know that in big companies we can seperate FRONTEND and BACKEND teams with dividing project into two piecies: Spring REST backend - and jQuery+HTML frontend - and let frontenders do their job. But is the point not to use Freemarker for jQuery and vice versa?

Looking forward to hearing from you guys ;)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it still RESTful practice?

RESTful services have the following 4 characteristics:

- they are **stateless**, which means that each request is independent and does not require information from any previous request
- they use **HTTP verbs** for defining actions
- they are **resource-oriented**
- has a certain **representation**, such as JSON and XML

You can serve as much HTML5+jQuery as you want, with the condition that it is stateless. The way you are explaining it, it isn't stateless => **it isn't RESTful**.

I would suggest you leave you HTML5+jQuery logic in the frontend part of you application, while the backed just serves up JSON objects. It's the most wholesome method out there so far and it gives you a RESTful backend to work with.

Frontends can't be RESTful as they depend on sessions, which are not stateless.

> I know that in big companies we can seperate FRONTEND and BACKEND teams with dividing project into two piecies

Like I said, it's best that you separate into frontend and backend, it is not something that only big companies do, it is a design practice favored by many, including small projects, as the advantages benefit everyone.

> What are differences between using template languages like Freemarker/Velocity and using HTML5 + jQuery?

The difference is that you do not benefit from the syntax and expression language offered by a template engine. You would have to create your own Spring-driven templates in which you integrate HTML5+jQuery. In Freemarker/Velocity/Thymeleaf or whatever you get an expression langauge that helps you with its expression features to build the actual HTML. So actually, it's not a question of differences between HTML5+jQuery and Freemarker, its a questions of differences between Spring default templates and Freemarker, because you can integrate HTML5+jQuery in both. It's the template engine that's different and you have a different language to work with for your templates.

Comment: According to Fielding, if your API isn't using HATEOAS, it isn't RESTful. You can take that as you will.

Comment: Depends, I would rephrase it as "not fully mature REST model", according to the Richardson maturity model (http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html). So without hypermedia, you would have a level 2 REST model. One of the main advantages of a level 3 is easier client development for that REST interface, whose usefulness depends on the need of the developers/requirements.

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with the RMM. I'm just saying that the guy who invented REST says it isn't RESTful if it's not level 3. Whether you care or not is up to you.

Comment: @GabrielRuiu please look at my next comment under your, I dont know how to notify you in next comment ;)